# Difficulty deserialize object from postgreSQL database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, postgresql, serialization, deserialization

I'm working on creating an android application that serializes objects and stores them into a PostgreSQL database that is running on a cloud9 VM. Then when the app starts up, it will download the object from the database and deserialize it.

I'm running into issues when trying to deserialize as it doesn't create the object. I will mention that I tested this code on Netbeans as follows and it worked.

```
//serialize - input is an arraylist of recipe objects
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
os.writeObject(input);
String serialized_input = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()); //bos.toString();
os.close();

//deserialize
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(serialized_input.getBytes()));
ObjectInputStream oInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
ArrayList<Recipe> input_Restored = (ArrayList<Recipe>) 
oInputStream.readObject();
```

My environment is as follows:
PostgreSQL 9.3, NodeJS/ Express for the server, pg for the postgresql adapter, cloud9 ubuntu VM, android studio with app running API 26

Here is my SQL file, I store the serialized object as a text.

```
drop database if exists recipes;
create database recipes;

\c recipes;

create table recipe (
    idrecipe SERIAL,
    userRecipes text NOT NULL,
    adminRecipes text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idrecipe)
    );
```

Here is my express api method (may not be relevant)

```
app.get('/add-recipe-admin', async (req, res) => {
    var data = {obj: req.query.object};
    console.log(data.obj+"\n");
    await pool.query('update recipe set adminRecipes = $1', [data.obj]);
    res.json({status: 'updated admin recipes'});
});
```

Here is my serialization in android studio

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
os.writeObject(RecipeList); //arraylist of objects
serialized_input = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()); 
os.close();
LoginHandler lh = new LoginHandler();
jsonString = lh.makeServiceCall("https://cpsc-350-psethr.c9users.io:8082/add-recipe-admin?object="+serialized_input);
```

Here is my deserialization in android studio

```
jsonString = lh.makeServiceCall("https://cpsc-350-psethr.c9users.io:8082/get-all-recipes");
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(jsonString);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(ob.get("adminrecipes").toString().getBytes()));
ObjectInputStream oInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
CreateRecipePage.RecipeList = (ArrayList<Recipe>) oInputStream.readObject(); //At this point it doesn't create any objects
```

I know that this may not be the best approach to storing serialized objects in a database but, I'm trying to make it work. I'm at a loss at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated.